# JavaScript heap out of memory with realy huge mongo bulk insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Let take this sample

```
export let index = (req: Request, res: Response) => {


for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let bulk = Faker.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    for (let y = 0; y < 200000; y++) {
        bulk.insert({
            name: randomName(),
            nights: Math.random(),
            price: Math.random(),
            type1: Math.random(),
            type2: Math.random(),
            type3: Math.random(),
            type4: Math.random(),
            departure: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(randomAreaID()),
            destination: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(randomAreaID()),
            refundable: randomBool(),
            active: randomBool(),
            date_start: randomDate(),
            date_end: randomDate(),
        });
    }
    bulk.execute();
}


return res.json({data: true});

};
```

With this code I try to insert "some" documents to my collection.

I use initializeUnorderedBulkOp but If I try to save more than 1 million docs then I have a memory issue

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I know that I can increase the memory but I want to find a better solution. Because now I need 2m records but in the future i will need 100m.

Any suggestion to avoid memory issues?

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have to be able to insert two hundred thousand records at once? On this scale, wouldn't it be a better idea to push that to a background processor that can crank through it in manageable chunks without leaving the user hanging?

Comment: In my application, these is a need to create 2 million "packages"... so yes... there is a particular reason. Sometimes there are more than 2m combinations. 

If i send it to the background I will have the same memory issue. So first of all i want to solve this problem. In php if I split it to chunks there is no problem because it is sync operation

Answer (score 3):

Async/Await is the solution. 200.000.000 documents without heap out of memory. Unlimited is now the limit....

```
let bulkPromise = (data) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (data.length > 0) {
        let bulk = Faker.collection.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        data.forEach((d) => {
            bulk.insert(d);
        })
        bulk.execute(() => {
            resolve(true);
        });
    } else {
        resolve(false);
    }
});
}

export let index = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    let data = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < 200000; y++) {
        data.push({
            name: randomName(),
            nights: Math.random(),
            price: Math.random(),
            type1: Math.random(),
            type2: Math.random(),
            type3: Math.random(),
            type4: Math.random(),
            departure: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(randomAreaID()),
            destination: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(randomAreaID()),
            refundable: randomBool(),
            active: randomBool(),
            date_start: randomDate(),
            date_end: randomDate(),
        });
    }
    await bulkPromise(data).then((data) => {
        console.log(i);
    });

}

return res.json({data: true});


};
```